# ISO 8583 Data Field Length

Tags: iso8583

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583), it explains the data types of the data fields as shown below:

[image]

*Additionally, each field may be either fixed or variable length. If variable, the length of the field will be preceded by a length indicator.*

So according to that table, what would the following types mean? I couldn't fully understand it.

**1.** `n ..19`

**2.** `n 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. means the field is variable and can contain a value *up-to* 19 chars.
2. i didn't see this definition (with a space) so I guess the table is mis-formatted on Wikipedia, but n10 means it is a fixed length field containing 10 chars, while n.10 means it's a LVAR (L=one digit, LL=2 digits etc.) field containing up-to 10 chars.

Answer (score 0):

n ..19 means MAX length 19 with numeric value of Data Element

n 10 means fix length with numeric value

Answer (score 0):

Just like K3N and Tush said, but with little addition .. means variable length with zero padded if length only 5, means the length indicator would be 05, while the one without .. , it has fixed length the data shown on stream only have 5 digits data without length indicator